# The inferior stopped because it received signal from the Operating System error on resizable scrollarea

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a QScrollArea inside QTabWidget and I have a QWidget beside my QTabWidget. I want QScrollArea to be resized when my main window is resized, so I have made this code like this:

```
void frmSummaryContact::on_btnAddNewContact_clicked()
{
    MainWindow *mnWindow = qobject_cast<MainWindow *>(this->parent()->parent()->parent()->parent()->parent()->parent());
    QTabWidget *tbWidget = qobject_cast<QTabWidget *>(this->parent()->parent()->parent()->parent());
    frmDetailContact *frm = new frmDetailContact(mnWindow, "input", -1, mnWindow->rightPane());

    QScrollArea *scrlForm = new QScrollArea;
    scrlForm->setWidgetResizable(true);
    scrlForm->setWidget(frm);

    mnWindow->AddNewTab(tbWidget, scrlForm, "Add Contact");
}
```

my QTabWidget is in different form, so I cast it with qobject_cast. Meanwhile in another form, I have a toogle button to hide QWidget so my QTabWidget get wider. So in that form I have a code like this:

```
void frmDetailContactToggle::on_btnSearch_clicked()
{
    MainWindow *mnWindow = qobject_cast<MainWindow *>(this->parent()->parent()->parent());
    QLayoutItem *child;

    while ((child = mnWindow->rightPane()->layout()->takeAt(0)) != 0)
        child->widget()->setVisible(false);

    mnWindow->rightPane()->setVisible(false);
    QScrollArea *scrlContent = qobject_cast<QScrollArea *>(mnWindow->tabContentWidget()->currentWidget());
    scrlContent->setWidgetResizable(false);
    mnWindow->tabContentWidget()->setGeometry(mnWindow->tabContentWidget()->x(), mnWindow->tabContentWidget()->y(), m_width - mnWindow->tabContentWidget()->x() - 10, mnWindow->tabContentWidget()->height());
    scrlContent->setWidgetResizable(true);
    m_showRightPane = false;
}
```

I have realized that I can't change the geometry when WidgetResizable is true. It showed "The inferior stopped because it received signal from the Operating System" error. So I thought about making it false, changing the geometry, and making it true again. But when I want to make it true, I encounter the same error. Could anyone please help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

if your program used uninitialized pointers,that may causes SIGSEGV.